# Cross domain issue in calling a restful API using Angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to access a restful API. This gives error. How to overcome this Cross domain issue?

The error is `'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource`

```
function Hello($scope, $http) {

$http.get('http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?q=London&format=json&num_of_days=5&key=atf6ya6bbz3v5u5q8um82pev').
    success(function(data) {
        alert("Success");
    }).
    error(function(data){
       alert("Error");
    });
}
```

This is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/2654/

Answer (score 5):

A better way to do this ([fiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/ncapito/R7XDh/)) is to use [`$http.jsonp`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/%24http#jsonp) .

```
var url = 'http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx';
return $http.jsonp(url, {
    params: {
        callback: 'JSON_CALLBACK',
        q: 'London',
        format:'json',
        num_of_days: 5,
        key: 'atf6ya6bbz3v5u5q8um82pev'
    }
});
```

Notice the `JSON_CALLBACK` query string parameter I added.  Behind the scenes angular uses that to setup its callbacks for you.  Without it it will break.

Answer (score 1):

Use JSONP for escape Cross Domain

```
 var request_url = 'http://api.worldweatheronline.com/free/v1/weather.ashx?q=London&format=json&num_of_days=5&key=atf6ya6bbz3v5u5q8um82pev&callback=JSON_CALLBACK';

$http({
  method: 'JSONP',
  url: request_url
}).success(function(data, status , header, config){
      alert('Success')
})
.error(function(data, status , header, config){
      alert('error')
});
```

Comment: There are two pieces to this `method:JSONP` and the callback you added to the end of the URL string.  Please explain these details and I will give you +1.

Comment: @Nix JSONP is used for making cross domain request & callback is JSONP format in which sever should wrap the response data with callback method e.g if u send url param callback=my_result then on server side you need to generate response with wrapping callback value as function  e.g   my_result({"id", 1 });